# Google Analytics use with Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, google-analytics

I have not found any information about this, so Ill ask here.

Can you connect Google Analytics to your Oracle Database and use their funktions and features to analyse the Database?

Cheers,

~Vulk

Comment: You could load the data into an Oracle database.  You are likely to find that BigQuery is a more suitable solution.

Comment: We do not want to load data into a data base, but rather read and analyze the data inside the oracle database.
For example, we got sold products in the database.
And we would like to know how many products where sold each month by accessing our database with google analytics. Is something like that possible?

Comment: the database has built in analytic features...but the short answer to your question is, 'No'